# Tomcat manager showing 403 on ubuntu droplet

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, digital-ocean, tomcat8

I have procured ubuntu droplet of digital ocean, I am facing issue in configuring access to tomcat manager. I have followed the following tutorial step by step and completed all the steps-
https://cloud.digitalocean.com/support/suggestions?article=how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04&page=0&query=tomcat%20manager

In fact I can access tomcat home page on server-ip:8080 but getting access denied issue on manager/html

This is my tomcat-users.xml-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
 version="1.0">
<!--
NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary. It is
  strongly recommended that you do NOT use one of the users in the commented out
  section below since they are intended for use with the examples web
  application.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are intended for use with the
  examples web application. They are wrapped in a comment and thus are ignored
  when reading this file. If you wish to configure these users for use with the
  examples web application, do not forget to remove the <!.. ..> that surrounds
  them. You will also need to set the passwords to something appropriate.
-->
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

I have tried my combinations of users and roles but every time I am getting access denied. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a context for the Manager App and allow access from Tomcat 8.5.x

Under your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/` home create a file manager.xml

manager.xml content, note my source is 172.31.254.37 (my computer), change this to your source :

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="172\.31\.254\.37" />
</Context>
```

Make sure your User/Roles are defined in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

```
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-status"/>
```

You need to do the same for host-manager if needed

Kind Regards,

Jacques de Jager

Comment: My PC is not the one with static/ external IP. How to allow all the hosts?

Comment: Use the wildcard ".*" for "any" - example below:                           <Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow=".*" />
</Context>